# Magento2 admin account disabled error

Tags: magento2, admin, error, login

How to enable admin account.

I get account disabled.

[image]

I tried to :

1. `php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin` (admin - username)
2. `` UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('mypassword') WHERE `username` = 'admin'; ``
3. Cleared cache and ran `setup upgrade`.

But still, I'm unable to log in.

Comment: Thanks worked , [now I can login](https://qatarliving.online/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run below query to direct database.

Example is for reset password for admin user.

> UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword',
>   256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';

**NewPassword** : Replace it with your password.

I hope it will work for you. let me know if you any difficulty.

Comment: cool..thanks worked... but why dint  php bin/magento admin:user:unlock  admin dint work?

Comment: My solution is for if you want reset admin password from directly from database.

Comment: what about this? UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('mypassword') WHERE `username` = 'admin';

Comment: It will work for magento 1.x.

Comment: it is useful when you do not know why does admin:user:unlock  not unlock the account

Answer (score 10):

Run below command to root directory using SSH.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

command will unloack user and after you can login with your existing username and password.

Answer (score 0):

If the admin account is inactive, you can't unlock it from the CLI.
You have to have access to the database and check *is_active* field from the *admin_user* table.

[image]